# How to produce a formatted date string in Q/KDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang, isodate

How can one produce an ISO date string "yyyy-MM-dd" from a Q date type? I looked at concatenating the various parts but am not even able to get the day/month, e.g. `d:2015.12.01;d.month` prints `2015.12`, i.e. more than just the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
q)"-" sv "." vs string[2015.12.01]
"2015-12-01"
```

`vs` vector from string, splits by "." above; 
`sv` string to vector, join by "-" above.

Remember a string is just a char array, so you can grab each part as you require with indexing. But the above is useful as the resulting vector of `vs` gives a 3-length vector that you manipulate any way you like

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to do it on a large scale (i.e. a large vector/list of dates or a column in a table) and you're sure your dates are always well-formed, then you could use a dot-amend:

```
q)update .[;(::;4 7);:;"-"]string date from ([] date:2#.z.D)
date
------------
"2016-01-04"
"2016-01-04"
```

This way you wouldn't have to apply to "each" entry of the vector/list, it works on the vector/list itself.

Comment: This is faster than the accepted answer and hence what I would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the shortest (and cleanest) option for ISO8601 UTC timestamp available since at least kdb v3.4 would be to use [`.h.iso8601`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth/#hiso8601-iso-timestamp) builtin

i.e.

```
q).h.iso8601 .z.p
"2020-11-09T15:42:19.292301000"
```

Or, if you just need milliseconds similar to what JS toISOString() does, use:

```
q).isotime:{(23#.h.iso8601 x),"Z"}
q).isotime[.z.p]
"2020-11-09T16:02:02.601Z"
q).isotime[2015.12.01]
"2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Note `.z.p` is important, as `.h.iso8601 .z.P` would silently give you local time without timezone (`+0100` etc) so it would still be interpreted as UTC by compliant ISO8601 parser :(

Answer (score 1):

Check-out this [GitHub library](https://github.com/aa1024/datetimeQ/blob/master/libs/dtf.q) for datetime formatting. It supports the excel way of formatting date and time. It might not be the right fit for formatting a large number of objects.

```
q).dtf.format["yyyy-mm-dd"; 2018.06.08T01:02:03.456]  
"2018-06-08"
```

time formatting :

```
q).dtf.format["yyyy-mmmm-dd hh:uu AM/PM"; 2018.01.08T01:02:03.456]  
"2018-January-08 01:02 AM"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using something like this:

```
q)ymd:{[x;s](4#d),s,(2#-5#d),s,-2#d:string[x]}
q)ymd[.z.D;"-"]
"2016-01-25"
q)ymd[.z.D;"/"]
"2016/01/25"
q)ymd[.z.D;""]
"20160125"
```

Or for tables:

```
q)t:([]a:5#1;5#.z.d)
q)update s:ymd[;"-"] each d from t
a d          s
-------------------------
1 2016.01.26 "2016-01-26"
1 2016.01.26 "2016-01-26"
1 2016.01.26 "2016-01-26"
1 2016.01.26 "2016-01-26"
1 2016.01.26 "2016-01-26"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the separator like `-` or `/` in the update statement.

```
update s:{ssr[string x;".";y]}'[d;"-"] from ([]a:5#1;5?.z.d)
a d          s
-------------------------
1 2010.12.31 "2010-12-31"
1 2012.08.24 "2012-08-24"
1 2004.12.05 "2004-12-05"
1 2000.10.02 "2000-10-02"
1 2006.09.10 "2006-09-10"
```