# How to format a Date in Q language (KDB) to MM/DD

Tags: jquery, date, kdb, q-lang

I'm a beginner to KDB/Q Langage, and I'm looking to find a way to convert a date object (or its string representation) to the format MM/DD. For example, I have 2016-09-23 and I would like to format it to 09/23.

There is another thread relating to this subject, but I am not sure how helpful it'd be : [How to produce a formatted date string in Q/KDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593508/how-to-produce-a-formatted-date-string-in-q-kdb)

In Q Language, is there any function similar to the ones like **convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)** in SQL?

Comment: Why does this have the `jquery` tag on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your strings are in a standard format (i.e YYYY-MM-DD), it will be quicker to use indexing @ depth.

```
q)list:("2016-09-23";"2016-10-23") 
q)5_'.[list;(::;4 7);:;"/"]
"09/23" 
"10/23"
```

Comment: Why not; `q) .[-5#'list;(::;2);:;"/"]`

Answer (score 4):

No such convert function exists in Kdb+ - but you convert it yourself with some basic string manipulation in Kdb - an example:

```
q) show dt:.z.d
    2016.09.26
q)"/" sv 1 _ "." vs string dt
    "09/26"
```

See [`vs`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vs)(vector from scalar) and [`sv`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#sv) (scalar from vector) for more information on splitting / joining a string.

The code above also uses [`_`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#_-drop)(drop) to drop the first portion (year) of the date after the sting has been split by "."

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
q)"/"0:(" **";"-")0:enlist "2016-09-23"
"09/23"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a very large vector, and provided you're not set on using a "/", this will be pretty fast:

```
q)dts:.z.d+til 1000000;
q)string[dts][;8 9 4 5 6]
"29.06"
"30.06"
"01.07"
"02.07"
```

If you want the "/":

```
"/"^string[dts][;8 9 10 5 6]
```

Misread the question; this is for DD/MM format.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [GitHub library](https://github.com/aa1024/datetimeQ/blob/master/libs/dtf.q) for datetime formatting. It supports the excel way of formatting date and time. Though it might not be the right fit for formatting a very large number of objects.

```
q).dtf.format["mm/dd"; 2016.09.23]  
"09/23"

q).dtf.format["yy/m/d"; 2016.09.03]  // another example
"16/9/3"
```